# Responsive CSS on Display-Listings-Shortcode

Tags: css, wordpress, plugins

I installed a plug-in called Display-listings-shortcode, and added the columns-extension to allow for columns the blogs halfway down the homepage at [RitaNaomi.com](http://ritanaomi.com) will be horizontally displayed on a web browser. It looked whacky at first with titles being scrunched beside and underneath the image, but eventually i figured out how to edit the .display-posts-listing class to change the display

```
.display-posts-listing .listing-item {padding-bottom:30;}

.listing-item
{
  float:left;
  width:22%;
  margin: 40px
  }
```

But when I look at it on a mobile device, they're all scrunched together as if it was still being displayed on a laptop. I want to have it listed vertically and not horizontally, because thats the way it would fit best.

I tried (and it didn't work) to use @media to change it through the css, but it didn't work. 
    @media handheld {

```
 .display-posts-listing .listing-item {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
   }

 .display-posts-listing img {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `@media handheld {}` since it's been deprecated according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

You're better off targeting pixel-width values. You may need a couple queries, and some of the oldschool standards were `1023px`, `767px`. Feel free to replace the `900px` below with whatever works for you.

```
@media only screen and ( max-width: 900px ){
   .display-posts-listing .listing-item {
       /* CSS Here */
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removed the custom CSS that was already added from the original theme. It was interfering with the Columns display.

Not using @media handheld {} because it was deprecated (thanks to xhynk for the response), and instead used the command (max-width: 768) , the point at which the title and image css look funky.

To make the title display on its own line on a bigger screen, i added this to my CSS:

```
.display-posts-listing .listing-item .title { display: block; }
```

And now i'm using the above media query to figure out how to style it on smaller devices.

Complete CSS: https://gist.github.com/billerickson/17149d6e77b139c868640a0ed3c73b3a